# Is there a way to specify character encoding when using the StaxEventItemReader in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Right now it looks to me that the StaxEventItemReader does not give any way to explicitly specify character encoding of the xml being unmarshalled as of Spring Batch 3.x and 4.x. Am I right? Has anyone found a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I have no experience in Spring Batch, but I can see that they have added `public void setXmlInputFactory(XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory)` in [version 4.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/commit/edfbdbb82a61294c2ea7eaabeb1add29ca6cb068)

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, there is an open issue for this feature request here: [jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2795](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2795).

You are welcome to contribute if you want!